# How to remove space between columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap, 3 column web page. Currently there is a small amount of space between each column that I would like to remove. How can I do this without editing the bootstrap.css file? Thank you.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="customDiv">
                    <div id="collapsible-panels">
                        <p><a href="#">Question One goes here?</a></p>
                        <div><p><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></p></div>
                        <p><a href="#">Question Two goes here?</a></p>
                        <div><p>Answer to Question Two goes here.</p></div>
                        <p><a href="#">Question Three goes here?</a></p>
                        <div><p>Answer to Question Three goes here.</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="customDiv">Main Content Area</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="customDiv">Right Side Bar</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You'd need to override Bootstrap's column padding on all the columns you want to do this on. A rule like `div.container > div.row > div { padding-left:0; padding-right:0; }` might work if it's loaded after Bootstrap's CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-left` & `padding-right` from `col-*-*` classes in a new css file by giving them an additional class (in my case `div-holder`), like:

CSS:

```
.div-holder {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 div-holder">
      <div class="customDiv">
        <div id="collapsible-panels">
          <p><a href="#">Question One goes here?</a></p>
          <div><p><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></p></div>
          <p><a href="#">Question Two goes here?</a></p>
          <div><p>Answer to Question Two goes here.</p></div>
          <p><a href="#">Question Three goes here?</a></p>
          <div><p>Answer to Question Three goes here.</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 div-holder">
      <div class="customDiv">Main Content Area</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 div-holder">
      <div class="customDiv">Right Side Bar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```